# LibreOffice Calc Date Insert - Ctrl + ;

Tags: libreoffice-calc

For some time now I've been able to insert the date into LibreOffice Calc cells by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> combination like in Excel.

With regard to this I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to make it insert only the DATE without the time (right now it inserts ddmmyy hhmmss).
2. Where is this option located in the menu as I couldn't find it anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

In LibreOffice 4.1:

- Date: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>
- Time: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: Some keyboard layouts require you to press the shift key to produce a semicolon and thus you can only insert the time but not the date. This can be circumvented by setting a custom keyboard shortcut for date insertion: Go to Tools>Customize>Keyboard, and on the bottom search for Insert>Current Date